# best way to do a http request from a spring 3 controller

Tags: java, json, spring-mvc

I've a Spring 3 Controller and it has to do a HTTP request [not a web service call] to another server which will give JSON response, controller then need to parse this JSON response and use it in JSP.

- Are there standard spring classes which I can use?
- Can I use Apache Http Client API for this?
- What is best way to implement this?
- Does spring has classes to parse JSON text?

Comment: Isn't a HTTP request to another server a RESTful GET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HTTP client from apache is good, also look into jackson which will provide JSON parsing (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-core).

**UPDATE:**
Something else you can look into is Spring's [RestTemplate](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html). This might be even easier to use than HTTP client.

Comment: Thank You, will go ahead and use Apache Http Client and Jackson.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to perform HTTP request to another server I recommend you to user Apache HTTP client. You can configure it using Spring XML and inject into the context just as any other bean.

Comment: Thank You, will go ahead and use Apache Http Client and Jackson.